# IContextMenu3 HandleMenuMsg2 in p/Invoke

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I am having an issue with p/Invoke and the context menu system.  I am able to call out and get the menu handle and populate the menu items just fine, but when I try to get the IContextMenu2 and IContextMenu3 objects, while I can get them, their message handlers don't seem to be doing anything, except possibly crashing my window proc.

Here are the declares in C# for the IContextMenu, IContextMenu2 and IContextMenu3 interfaces that I have, which I added to the Windows API Code Pack:

```
[ComImport,
Guid("000214e4-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IContextMenu
{

    [PreserveSig]
    HResult QueryContextMenu( 
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In]  IntPtr hmenu,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In]  UInt16 indexMenu,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In]  uint idCmdFirst,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In]  uint idCmdLast,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In]  uint uFlags);


    HResult InvokeCommand(
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In]  CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOPTR pici);
    [PreserveSig]

    HResult InvokeCommand(
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In]  CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pici);

    HResult InvokeCommand(
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In]  IntPtr pici);

    [PreserveSig]
    HResult GetCommandString( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In]  IntPtr idCmd,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In]  uint uType,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In, Out] ref uint pReserved,
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        [In] IntPtr pszCommand,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In] uint cchMax);

};

[ComImport,
Guid("000214f4-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IContextMenu2 : IContextMenu
{

    [PreserveSig]
    HResult HandleMenuMsg(
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In] uint uMsg,
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In] IntPtr wParam,
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In] IntPtr lParam);
}

[ComImport,
Guid("BCFCE0A0-EC17-11D0-8D10-00A0C90F2719"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IContextMenu3 : IContextMenu2
{
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult HandleMenuMsg2(
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In] uint uMsg,
        /* [annotation][in] */
        [In] IntPtr wParam, 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        [In] IntPtr lParam,
        /* [annotation][out] */
        [Out]
        out IntPtr plResult);
}
```

Here is the window proc, and the public variables on the VB side:

```
Private _icx2 As IContextMenu2 = Nothing
Private _icx3 As IContextMenu3 = Nothing

Dim oldProc As WndProcDelegate
Dim rRet As IntPtr

Dim _hctx3 As Boolean = False
Dim _hctx2 As Boolean = False

Dim newProc _
    As New WndProcDelegate _
(Function(hwnd As IntPtr, _
          uMsg As UInteger, _
          wParam As IntPtr, _
          lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr


     If _hctx3 Then
         rRet = 0
         If _icx3.HandleMenuMsg2(uMsg, wParam, lParam, rRet) = HResult.Ok Then
             Return rRet
         End If
     ElseIf _hctx2 Then
         If _icx2.HandleMenuMsg(uMsg, wParam, lParam) = HResult.Ok Then
             Return 0
         End If
     End If

     'Select Case uMsg
     '    Case WM_INITMENUPOPUP, WM_DRAWITEM, WM_MENUCHAR, WM_MEASUREITEM
     '        If _hctx3 Then
     '            rRet = 0
     '            _icx3.HandleMenuMsg2(uMsg, wParam, lParam, rRet)
     '            Return rRet
     '        End If

     'End Select

     Return oldProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
 End Function)
```

As you can see, I had tried to do it as prescribed in the MSDN article on the matter, and follow only the relevant messages, and now I'm doing it sort of as adapted from Raymond Chen's article on the same topic.

Finally, this is how I am going about the entire endeavor in the code to activate the popup:

```
Dim handleWnd As New Form

Dim ip As IntPtr, _
    ip2 As IntPtr

' Set the new window proc for the new window handle.
oldProc = SetWindowLongPtr(handleWnd.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, newProc)

' Call the helper function to get the context menu
GetUIObjectOfFile(handleWnd.Handle, fileName, New Guid(IID_IContextMenu), mnu)

' That did not work, abort.
If mnu Is Nothing Then Return

' Create a popup menu
hMenu = CreatePopupMenu
mnu.QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, &H7FFF, 0)

' Get the COM interface for IContextMenu2
' 000214f4-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
ip = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(mnu)
Marshal.QueryInterface(ip, New Guid(IID_IContextMenu2), ip2)
_icx2 = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ip2)

If _icx2 IsNot Nothing Then _hctx2 = True

' Get the COM interface for IContextMenu3
' BCFCE0A0-EC17-11D0-8D10-00A0C90F2719
ip = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(mnu)
Marshal.QueryInterface(ip, New Guid(IID_IContextMenu3), ip2)
_icx3 = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ip2)

If _icx3 IsNot Nothing Then _hctx3 = True

mi = TrackPopupMenuEx(hMenu, TPM_RETURNCMD, x, y, handleWnd.Handle, Nothing)

' Revert the window proc
SetWindowLongPtr(handleWnd.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, oldProc)

If _hctx3 Then
    _hctx3 = False
    _icx3 = Nothing
End If
If _hctx2 Then
    _hctx2 = False
    _icx2 = Nothing
End If
```

When I was NOT trying to run the menu handler functions, the menu displayed just fine, except for a lack of Share With and Open With menus.  The Send-To and Add To Library ones populated just fine without invoking any of this behavior.  AFTER trying to invoke this behavior the appearance of the menu is completely unpredictable but usually results in icons that disappear as you hover over them, and no menus populated, at all.

I DO have a function I wrote in C++ that does this form me, and I also can build the menus, myself, as I have been doing, using the IAssocHandler interface.  I was hoping to do it all native in .NET through p/Invoke without having to resort to C, and I also want to know exactly why this code doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any kind help you can offer.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is the overall goal?

Comment: I have a program that works with files and folders that I'm working on that I'm doing in VB, for the time-being, I may end up writing the whole thing in C++ except working with controls and forms in C can be a real PITA, although I don't know that this is any better.

The goal is simply to be able to present the shell menu to the end user when they're in a mode where that should be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the NativeWindow class and SHBindToObject to get the IContextMenu2 and IContextMenu3 interfaces.